# Fabric methods exceptions

Tags: python, exception, fabric

I try to make Fabric func, which checks if Apache installed:

```
from fabric.api import *

def check_apache():
    try:
        result = local('httpd -v', capture=True)
    except:
        print "check_apache exception"
```

But if httpd is not installed I get:

```
$ fab check_apache

Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 127) while executing 'ahttpd -v'

Aborting.
check_apache exception

Done.
```

How can I get correct exception for Fabric `local()` method? So I need to get exception and continue executing without any Fabric error messages:

```
$ fab check_apache
check_apache exception

Done.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `env.warn_only` to `True` or use the setting context manager. See http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.3/api/core/context_managers.html?highlight=warn#fabric.context_managers.settings

Comment: env.warn_only==True doesn't help me.

Comment: Have you used it like this?
with settings(env.warn_only=True):
    local(...)

Comment: Yes, sure. I got: Warning: local() encountered an error (return code 127) while executing 'ahttpd -v'

Comment: @baobee: I'm sure you've figured this out by now, but that'd be `env.warn_only = True`.